# Use streams in a multipart upload to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming

The current project I'm working on requires that multiple processes upload data to a single file in S3. This data comes from multiple sources in parallel, so in order to process all the sources as fast as possible we'll use multiple Nodejs instances to listen to the sources. There are memory and storage constraints, so load all ingested data to memory or store in disk and then perform a single upload is out of question.

To respect those constraints I implemented a streamed upload: it buffers a small portion of the data from a single source and pipes the buffer to an upload stream. This works really well when using a single nodejs process, but, as I mentioned, the goal is to process all sources in parallel. My first try was to open multiple streams to the same object key in the bucket. This simply overrides the file with the data from the last stream to close. So I discarded this option.

```
// code for the scenario above, where each process will open a separete stream to
// the same key and perform it's data ingestion and upload.
openStreamingUpload() {
  const stream = require('stream');
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const s3 = new this.AWS.S3(/* s3 config */);

  const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();

  const params = {
    Key: 'final-s3-file.txt',
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Body: passThrough
  };

  s3
    .upload(params)
    .promise();

  return passThrough;
}

async main() { // simulating a "never ending" flow of data
  const stream = openStreamingUpload();
  let data = await receiveData();;

  do {
    stream.write(data);
    data = await receiveData();
  } while(data);
  stram.close();
}
main();
```

Next I went to try the [multipart upload](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/using-aws-for-multi-instance-multi-part-uploads/) that the S3 API offers. At first, I create a multipart upload, obtain its ID and store it in a shared space. After that I try to open multiple multipart uploads on all nodejs processes the cluster will be using, with the same UploadId obtained beforehand. Each one of those multipart uploads should have a stream that will pipe the data received. The problem I came across was that the multipart upload needs to know the part length beforehand and as I'm piping a stream that I don't know when will close or the amount of data it will pipe, it's not possible to calculate it's size. Code inspired by [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/90a508ea1ad5256ba33637e3670597be).

```
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const s3 = new this.AWS.S3(/* s3 config */);
  async startMultipartUpload()
    const multiPartParams = {
      Key: 'final-s3-file.txt',
      Bucket: 'my-bucket'
    };
    const multipart = await s3.createMultipartUpload(multiPartParams).promise();

    return multipart.UploadId;
  }

  async finishMultipartUpload(multipartUploadId) {
    const finishingParams = {
      Key: 'final-s3-file.txt',
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      UploadId: multipartUploadId
    };
    const data = await s3.completeMultipartUpload(finishingParams).promise();

    return data;
  }

  async openMultiparStream(multipartUploadId) {
    const stream = require('stream');
    const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();

    const params = {
      Body: passThrough.,
      Key: 'final-s3-file.txt',
      Bucket: 'my-bucket',
      UploadId: multipartUploadId,
      PartNumber: // how do I know this part number when it's, in principle, unbounded?
    };

    s3
      .uploadPart(params)
      .promise();

    return passThrough 
  }

 // a single process will start the multipart upload
 const uploadId startMultipartUpload();
 async main() { // simulating a "never ending" flow of data
   const stream = openMultiparStream(uploadId);
   let data = await receiveData();;

   do {
     stream.write(data);
     data = await receiveData();
   } while(data);
   stram.close();
 }

 main(); // all the processes will receive and upload to the same UploadId
 finishMultipartUpload(uploadId); // only the last process to closm will finish the multipart upload.
```

Searching around, I came across [the article](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-s3-managed-uploader-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) from AWS the presents the `upload()` API method and says that it abstracts the multipart API to allow use of piped data streams to upload large files. So I wonder if its possible to obtain the uploadId from a streamed 'simple' upload, so I can pass this Id around the cluster and upload to the same object and still maintaining the streaming characteristic. Does anyone ever tried this type of scenario of a 'streamed multipart' upload?

Comment: did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @Purefan, unfortunately, no. Now, after getting more used to the AWS ecosystem, I would have used a Knesis Stream that pipes data to S3 and then trigger a Lambda function to reconstruct the multiple parts of the file into a new S3 object. For this problem in particular I ended up using the default upload with a single process.